# Get the node value using js or jquery in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2007, jquery, xslt

```
<tr>
    <td width="25%" class="ms-vb">
        <b>Inclusion:</b>
    </td>
    <td width="75%" class="ms-vb">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Inclusion" />
        <p></p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can i get the value of `@Inclusion` in the client?

Comment: What does the client (generated) HTML look like

Answer (score 1):

We got loads of SharePoint JQuery related samples on our site as it works very well with our free SharePoint Infuser product.

Check out the following resources:

- [SharePoint Infuser](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/SharePoint-Infuser-%28Free%29.aspx)
- [Overview of Blog postings](http://blog.muhimbi.com/search/label/Infuser)
- [Filtering example](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/09/add-real-time-filtering-to-all-lists.html)

Comment: Thanks but what i'm after is use an element tag like so e.g
<div id="inc"><xsl:value-of select="@Inclusion" />
</div>
and then use jquery to get the div value using the "inc" ID
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can get that element by getting its value by specifying attribute which is title. For example if your inclusion field is input then you can use something like this

`jQuery('input[title="Inclusion"]').val();`

This way I used to get the element values. In your case you need to check your DOM for your element type.

Hope this helps!